# Error getting value (multiple email addresses) from cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to send a PDF blob to multiple email addresses. The code that gets the value of the cell that contains multiple email addresses separated by commas returns a #N/A. When I try to run the script anyway, I get an error message Invalid email: #N/A. That error makes sense, but I can't figure out why I can't get a simple value from a cell. I may be working to many hours. :b

I can't see any reason why the .getRange().getValue(); should not work. The value in cell at row 14, column 12 is (changed to protect identity) ben.jones@email.org,juliajones@email.org,plaidjones@email.com 
All three comma-separated addresses are in one cell.

```
var emailTo = isr.getRange(14, 12).getValue();
var teacheremail = isr.getRange(8, 12).getValue();

MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: teacheremail, 
    cc: emailTo,
    subject: subject, 
    htmlBody: message,
    attachments: [attach]
  });
```

I'm new to GAS but learning lots. I'm hoping this code will send one email with the PDF blob attached to the teacheremail and cc that email to all the student and parent email addresses in cell L14.

Comment: I think that the reason of the error is due to `Invalid email: #N/A`. When the value of the cell is `#N/A`, the value retrieved by `getValue()` is `#N/A`. But in your question, the cell of `getRange(14, 12)` has the value of emails. So in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: column 2 or column 12? Your code includes `getRange(14, 12)`

Comment: It is actually column 12.

Comment: The entire spreadsheet is sensitive information that is restricted by state laws to share. I will try to mock something up as soon as I can get to it. In the meanwhile, if anyone knows of a specific bug or problem that prevents the getting of comma-separated email values for a cell using .getValue(), please help me out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You code works for me with the provided data, so the problem must be related to your spreadsheet. Waiting for your sample spreadsheet.